# How to get the Vue's element's child DOM?

Tags: html, vue.js, console

How to get the Vue's element's child DOM?

I have bellow code, I want to get the `<div>`'s `<input>` element.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#box',
  data: {
    pick: true,
    a: 'a'
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>


</head>
<body>

<div id="box">
  <input type="radio" v-model="pick" :value="a">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue-resource/1.3.4/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get that in Vue.js? Or in the Console?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: could u please add a vote up tp my answer?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think you should tell us what functionality do you want to realize.

For your question:in vue.js there is `ref` binding to get the reference of DOM elements.

```
//html
<div id="box">
  <input ref="domOfInput" type="radio" v-model="pick" :value="a">
</div>

//js code
 vm.$refs.domOfInput will be the DOM node
```